# Trying to email google sheet but it is coming up with response is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have around 10 sheets with sales from the day for each stall holder and each one is emailed out at night to the stall holder. All have the same script to email the spreadsheet out but now 3 are coming up with the error "Response is not defined".

Please can some one help me.

See below my script.

```
/* Send Spreadsheet in an email as PDF, automatically */
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  // Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
  const email = "Email for the stallholder";

  // Get the currently active spreadsheet URL (link)
  // Or use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("<>");
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();

var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10) 
{
    dd='0'+dd;
} 

if(mm<10) 
{
    mm='0'+mm;
} 
today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
console.log(today);

  // Subject of email message
  const subject = ("Daily Sales Summary - " + today);

  // Email Body can  be HTML too with your logo image - see ctrlq.org/html-mail
  const body = "<br>Hi Julie,<br>" + "<br>Please find attached your Daily Sales Summary.<br>" + "<br>Kind Regards,<br>" + "<br>"
    console.log('\n')

  // Base URL
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', ss.getId());

  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
    '&size=A4'
    '&portrait=true' + // orientation, false for landscape
    '&fitw=true&source=labnol' + // fit to page width, false for actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid='; // the sheet's Id

  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();

  // make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs
  const blobs = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i += 1) {
    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + exportOptions + sheets[i].getSheetId(), {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    })

    // convert the response to a blob and store in our array
    blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName('Daily Sales');
  }

  // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [response]

    });
}
```

Comment: `UrlFetchApp.fetch` is asynchronous. (this means it works 'outside' of the flow of your code so you are getting an 'undefined' on response as it hasn't initialised fully for some requests) You need a handler to wait for the response to complete. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch - you will see there is a `.then` section - this happens after the AJAX call and ensures the request has completed before trying to do anything further.

Answer (score 1):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Modification points:

- In your script, at the following part, `exportOptions` returns only `exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf`. Because `+` operator is not added after `'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'`.

  ```
  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
    '&size=A4'
    '&portrait=true' + // orientation, false for landscape
    '&fitw=true&source=labnol' + // fit to page width, false for actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid='; // the sheet's Id
  ```
- `const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(###)` is put in the for loop. And also `attachments: [response]` is used at the out of the for loop. By this, the error of `"Response is not defined"` occurs.

  - By the way, in your script, I think that even when `const` of `const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(###)` is modified to `var`, no error occurs.

When above points are reflected to your script, how about the following modification?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the for loop and the modified `exportOptions` are used. In this case, each sheet is added as each attachment file. So when there are 3 sheets in the Spreadsheet, 3 PDF files are sent as the attachment files.

Please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
    '&size=A4'
    '&portrait=true' + // orientation, false for landscape
    '&fitw=true&source=labnol' + // fit to page width, false for actual size
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid='; // the sheet's Id

  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();

  // make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs
  const blobs = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i += 1) {
    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + exportOptions + sheets[i].getSheetId(), {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    })

    // convert the response to a blob and store in our array
    blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName('Daily Sales');
  }

  // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [response]

    });
```

#### To:

```
const exportOptions =
  'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' +
  '&size=A4' +
  '&portrait=true' + // orientation, false for landscape
  '&fitw=true&source=labnol' + // fit to page width, false for actual size
  '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
  '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
  '&fzr=false' + // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  '&gid='; // the sheet's Id
const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
const sheets = ss.getSheets();
const blobs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i += 1) {
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + exportOptions + sheets[i].getSheetId(), {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token}});
  blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName('Daily Sales' + i);
}
if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: blobs});
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the modified `exportOptions` are used. And the for loop is not used. In this case, each sheet is added as one attachment file. So when there are 3 sheets in the Spreadsheet, 1 PDF file is sent as the attachment file.

Please modify as follows.

#### From:

This is the same with the pattern 1.

#### To:

```
const exportOptions =
  'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' +
  '&size=A4' +
  '&portrait=true' + // orientation, false for landscape
  '&fitw=true&source=labnol' + // fit to page width, false for actual size
  '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' + // hide optional headers and footers
  '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' + // hide page numbers and gridlines
  '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + exportOptions, {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token}});
if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: [response.getBlob()]});
```

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.